# The connection failed because of an error in initializing provider - SSAS 2005 - restored DB

Tags: backup, ssas, olap-cube

Hullo everyone.
After restoring a backup (comprehensive of security information) of AdventureWorksDW cube I am unable to log into it using windows authentication.

SQL Server Analysis service version is 2005 (9.00.1399.6), installed on a Windows 2003R2 machine joined to a domain.

Shoul you need any further information please do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: This back up from a different machine? If so see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594134/How-to-Fix-Orphaned-SQL-Users

Comment: @TonyHopkinson no, it is from the same machine, I will check your link though, thanks.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson This question refers to is a restore of an Analysis Services cube, not a relational database!

Answer (score 1):

Your user ID (or any group containing it) is probably not contained in any role of the Analysis Services database that you restored, and you included the security information when restoring. If you do not have Analysis Services server administration rights, then you cannot access the database. You could access the database in Management Studio using a user id that has administrative rights, either on the database, or on the whole server (by default the local administrators group of the server computer has Analysis Services server administration rights), and change the rights (below the "Roles" node of the database in Management Studio) so that you can access the database.

Or, you could ask someone having administrative rights to restore the database again, this time unchecking "Include security information" in the dialog. You probably cannot do this yourself, as if you do not have administration rights to a database, you cannot overwrite it by the restore.